# Using regex to extract (correction)

Tags: regex

I have my xml data [HERE](http://pastebin.com/98zg3tRX), I need to extract using Splunk IFX, Generated pattern (regex).

Example of my Xml: `<d:Message>(22/7)17:53 Accident on AYE (towards Tuas) after Jurong Port Rd Exit. Avoid lane 3.</d:Message>`

I have this expression that extract from word after until Exit. 
`(?i) (?P<on>on) (?P<expressway>[^.]+) (?P<afterbefore>at|after|before) (?P<wordafter>[^.]*?(?P<dummy>Exit\.))`

As this will return the `on`, `AYE (towards Tuas)`, `after`, `Exit`. How can I take out `AYE` rather than `AYE (towards Tuas)`. I am rather noob to regex and only need help on this part (extracting `AYE`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

I modified your expression to match the `(...)` text which then pulls it out of the capture group.

`(?P<on>on) (?P<expressway>[^.]+?)\s+(?:\([^)]*?\)\s+)?(?P<afterbefore>at|after|before) (?P<wordafter>[^.]*?(?P<dummy>Exit\.))`

[image]

In this live demo, hover over the blue highlights to see how it matched: 
[Live Demo](http://regexr.com?35o0q)

Comment: What app makes this graphic?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ for that graphic I'm using a website http://www.debuggex.com/ which is currently in Beta